# SQL Trouble Understanding query

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have the following query

```
SELECT * FROM TABLEA C
WHERE C.VAL = 'SENIOR' 
AND C.TYPE = 'HELLO'
AND C.DATE = (SELECT MAX(DATE) from TABLEA WHERE TYPE = 
'HELLO'  AND C.ID=ID)
```

I am having trouble understanding what the C.ID=ID in the inner query actually does in this query. I am not sure if it is possible to understand the query and answer for anyone without demo data but I do not have a demo data at the moment.

Comment: Here for C.ID ,C refers to the TABLEA data.

Comment: I understand that but what is it logically doing by accessing the data for tableA and equaling it to ID

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, it ensures that rows in the subquery only match rows in the the outer query with the same ID.  However, if TABLEA.ID is a primary key, then the subquery looks a bit redundant.  Probably best to illustrate with an example.  Let's assume ID is not a primary key so there can be multiple rows with the same ID:

```
ID        VAL       TYPE      DATE
1         SENIOR    HELLO     01-JAN-1970
1         SENIOR    HELLO     02-JAN-1970
1         JUNIOR    HELLO     03-JAN-1970
1         SENIOR    HELLO     03-JAN-1970
2         SENIOR    HELLO     04-JAN-1970
2         JUNIOR    HELLO     05-JAN-1970
2         SENIOR    HELLO     05-JAN-1970
2         JUNIOR    BYE       06-JAN-1970
3         JUNIOR    BYE       06-JAN-1970
```

The subquery ensures that only the row with max(date) and type HELLO will be selected from rows with the same id so the result with the above data would return:

```
ID        VAL       TYPE      DATE
1         JUNIOR    HELLO     03-JAN-1970
2         JUNIOR    HELLO     05-JAN-1970
```

Basically, it would just return the row with the newest date for rows with a given id that are also of type HELLO and val SENIOR so long as the row with the newest date also has a val of SENIOR.

Comment: No it is not a primary key. So what you mean is that the subquery will run for the rows that were selected in outer query based on the WHERE conditions?

Comment: Cool.  Okay, updated my response with an example.  Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks - Do you know of any resources where I can read of this more?

Comment: I'd probably try w3schools for a basic introduction. https://www.w3schools.com/sql/DEfaULT.asP.  From there you might read through the documentation for the specific database you're using, or go on amazon and buy a SQL book.

Comment: If you're specifically talking about subqueries, this looks pretty good: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/subqueries.html